# spring BOOT: basic auth only for some urls and db auth for others in spring BOOT

Tags: java, spring-boot, basic-authentication

Hi i am stuck on this issue for really long time now.
i want some rest apis to have basic authentication and some rest apis having db authententication.

I tried adding separate WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter, but its not working.
How can this be achieved in spring Boot?

Comment: Post. Some. Code.

Comment: Add some code/configuration etc. Also what do you mean with Basic authentication and DB authentication?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The security Filter was rejecting the Basic auth Urls..so i made those URLs open Url in Spring security.(no auth Urls)

So that when these Urls will come into Basic Auth Filter they will be authenticated.

So i created a FilterRegistrationBean for Basic Auth with Lowest_Precedence.

```
@Bean
  public FilterRegistrationBean registerBasicAuthFilter(BasicAuthFilter filter) {
      FilterRegistrationBean reg = new FilterRegistrationBean(filter);
      reg.setOrder(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE);
      return reg;
  }
```

> If you want your own Filter to go after Spring Security's you can create your own registration for Spring Security's filter and specify the order.

Sharing the Basic Auth Java class - Spring BOOT

- This includes authentication of user from db.(helps to rotate the
  user creds on the fly).

https://gist.github.com/kad9/b595910e1a659f91d199b910f699a2d2

This made my work simple to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot also does the same thing which Spring does , It is just the framework on the top of Spring framework to remove your boiler plater and make the configuraiton part easier.

You can refer to this link to see how it is being done in spring boot: https://www.devglan.com/spring-security/spring-boot-security-rest-basic-authentication

Comment: Thanks @ Ishant Gaurav, i tried this but was having issues with inmemory auth users and Db authentication services...either one of them was getting picked up for all Apis(URLS). So finally decided to go for the old way to handle these things using filters.